# Update Google Domains via Post request

Tags: powershell, dns

Google Domains recently added support for DDNS updating. I'm a little lost on how to make the Post request with their requirements. How exactly do things need to be passed? I know I need to pass the username, password, and domain.

Sample post string I would use:

```
$postParams = @{username='me';moredata='qwerty'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foobar -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

Details on how to use the API
https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en

```
POST /nic/update?hostname=subdomain.yourdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4 HTTP/1.1 
Host: domains.google.com 
Authorization: Basic base64-encoded-auth-string User-Agent: Chrome/41.0
your_email@yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script I modified to update the Google Domains DDNS via PowerShell. Just schedule it as an event using the task scheduler or include it in a batch.

```
#Your info goes here
$hostname = "yourhostname.com"
$user = "your_generated_dns_username"
$pwd = "your_generated_dns_password"
$pair = "$($user):$($pwd)"


#Get a page with your current IP
$MyIpPage = Invoke-WebRequest "https://domains.google.com/checkip"

#Make sure we got a IP back in the response
If ($MyIpPage.RawContent -match "(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}")
{
    #encode the username and password for the header
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"

    $headers = @{ Authorization =  $basicAuthValue }

    #Build up the URL
    $url = "https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname={0}&myip={1}" -f $hostname, $MyIpPage

    #Invoke the URL
    $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers
    $resp.Content #Expected answers that I found "good","nochg","nohost","badauth","notfqdn"
}
Else
{
 #fake response if we didn't get any IP
 "No IP"
}
```

Original script source: http://powershell.today/2014/03/powershell-and-dyndns-at-loopia/

Answer (score 0):

I would use System.Net.WebClient to connect to the webpage with basic authentication

```
$username="<username>"
$password="<password>"
$url="https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=<subdomain.yourdomain.com>&myip=<1.2.3.4>"
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
```

or if you wanted to use Invoke-WebRequest you will need to use get-credential for the username:password.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=<subdomain.yourdomain.com>&myip=<1.2.3.4>" -Credential $cred
```

Answer (score 0):

modified Tyler W's script

```
#Google Domains API information: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en
#Your Google Domains Dynamic DNS info goes here
$hostname = "HOSTNAMEHERE"
$user = "USERNAMEHERE"
$pwd = "PASSWORDHERE"
$pair = "$($user):$($pwd)"

#Get the domain to IP resolution
$MyDNS = (Resolve-DnsName $hostname).IPAddress
#Make sure we got a IP back in the response
If ($MyDNS -match "(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}")
{
    Write-Host "Current IP Address for $hostname`: $MyIp" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
Else
{
    Write-Warning "No IP Recieved!"
}
#Get a your current IP
$MyIp = (Invoke-WebRequest "https://domains.google.com/checkip").Content
#Make sure we got a IP back in the response
If ($MyIp -match "(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}")
{
    $NameHost = (Resolve-DnsName $MyIp).NameHost
    Write-Host "Current IP Address for $NameHost`: $MyIp" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
Else
{
    Write-Warning "No IP Recieved!"
}
If ($MyDNS -ne $MyIP)
{
    #encode the username and password for the header
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
    $headers = @{ Authorization =  $basicAuthValue }

    #Build up the URL
    $url = "https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname={0}&myip={1}" -f $hostname, $MyIp

    #Invoke the URL
    $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers
    # 
    switch -Wildcard ($resp.Content)
    {
       "good*" {Write-Host "The update was successful!" -ForegroundColor Green}
       "nochg*" {Write-Host "The supplied IP address $MyIp is already set for this host." -ForegroundColor Green}
       "nohost*" {Write-Warning "The hostname does not exist, or does not have Dynamic DNS enabled. `nHostname: $hostname"}
       "badauth*" {Write-Warning "The username / password combination is not valid for the specified host! `nUsername: $user`nPassword: $pwd"}
       "notfqdn*" {Write-Warning "The supplied hostname is not a valid fully-qualified domain name! `nHostname: $hostname"}
       "badagent*" {Write-Warning "Your Dynamic DNS client is making bad requests. Ensure the user agent is set in the request, and that you’re only attempting to set an IPv4 address. IPv6 is not supported."}
       "abuse*" {Write-Warning "Dynamic DNS access for the hostname has been blocked due to failure to interpret previous responses correctly."}
       "911*" {Write-Warning "An error happened on our end. Wait 5 minutes and retry."}
    }
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "DNS resolution and the current IP match, no need to update!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```